Running MD simulations with the xtb program
I am running MD simulations on a HPC cluster via the xtb program (xtb/6.5.0). However, I am only able to run calculations with GFN-FF, and not with GFN2-xTB for some reason.
This works:
xtb --input md.inp input.xyz --md --chrg 0 --gfnff  > MD_output

This doesn't work:
xtb --input md.inp input.xyz --md --chrg 0  > MD_output

My md.inp file looks like this:
$md
   temp=298.15 # in K
   time= 50.0  # in ps
   dump= 50.0  # in fs
   step=  2.0  # in fs
   velo=false
   nvt =true
   hmass=4.0
   shake=2
   sccacc=2.0
$end

The input.xyz file contains a geometry that was pre-optimized with GFN2-xTB (OPTIM) beforehand. Running with all the default settings (not including the md.inp file and not setting the charge) does not work either. The command seff doesn't work on my cluster. The job output files do not say anything interesting.
The MD_output file is very short and looks like this:

Does someone know how to fix this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Could you add your full output in a code block, please?

For some reason the website isn't letting me paste large pieces of text and automatically adds it as a picture. The picture does show everything in the output file (there is nothing after the *** line). Before the first line is the standard xtb output.

Unfortunately, there is no useful information there. Also, xTB is in version 6.7.1 now, you could try to update your installation.
